# Necessary conditions for limit of a recursive succession

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I was wondering if somebody could help me with this calculus problem.

Let $I$ be an interval and $f: I \to I$. Consider the sequence:

$x_0 \in I  , x_{n+1}=f (x_n), \quad \forall n \in \Bbb N$.

Find a necessary and sufficient condition (that can easily be verified) for the existence of a limit for the sequence.

Comment: Yes. In fact, I meant to write x$_{n+1}$=f(x$_n$). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but nevetheless: you can easily write many different sufficient conditions. For example, $f(x)\ge x$ is sufficient, but not necessary.